# Remove label from Steema Bar Chart

Tags: xamarin.ios, teechart

[image]

How remove the label of each bar in the chart

and need to set Title for the Chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How remove the label of each bar in the chart

```
  tChart1[0].Marks.Visible = false;
```

> and need to set Title for the Chart.

```
  tChart1.Header.Visible = true;
  tChart1.Header.Text = "Chart title";
```